# How to create C# Reflection to Lambda Expression returning boolean

Tags: c#, linq, generics, reflection, expression

I have an Specification interface and classes:

```
public interface ISpecification<TEntity> where TEntity : class, new()
{
    Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> SatisfiedBy();
}

public abstract class Specification<TEntity> : ISpecification<TEntity> where TEntity : class, new()
{
    public abstract Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> SatisfiedBy();
    public static Specification<TEntity> operator &(Specification<TEntity> leftSideSpecification, Specification<TEntity> rightSideSpecification)
    {
        return new AndSpecification<TEntity>(leftSideSpecification, rightSideSpecification);
    }
    public static Specification<TEntity> operator |(Specification<TEntity> leftSideSpecification, Specification<TEntity> rightSideSpecification)
    {
        return new OrSpecification<TEntity>(leftSideSpecification, rightSideSpecification);
    }
    public static Specification<TEntity> operator !(Specification<TEntity> specification)
    {
        return new NotSpecification<TEntity>(specification);
    }
    public static bool operator false(Specification<TEntity> specification)
    {
        return false;
    }
    public static bool operator true(Specification<TEntity> specification)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

public class Table1BySpecification: Specification<Table1>
{
    Propiedades Privadas
    Expression<Func<Table1, bool>> _Expression = null;

    public Table1BySpecification(Expression<Func<Table1, bool>> expression)
    {
        this._Expression = expression;
    }

    public override Expression<Func<Table1, bool>> SatisfiedBy()
    {
        return this._Expression;
    }
}
```

I create a Table1BySpecification so I can run from a generic function...

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetBySpecification(string propertyName, object propertyValue, propertyOperator ){

    ISpecification<Table1> Specification = new Table1BySpecification(t1 => t1.name == "test_name");          
    context.CreateDbSet<Table1>().Where(Specification.SatisfiedBy())
}
```

This works fine for Table1 entity, however I'd like to use TEntity instead, and use dynamic specification using reflection. Maybe I could have something like:

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetBySpecification(string propertyName = "name", object propertyValue = "test_name", string propertyOperator = "==" ){

    var source = typeof(TEntity); 
    var t = Expression.Parameter( source, "t" );
    var sourceProperty = Expression.MakeMemberAccess( arg, source.GetProperty( propertyName ) );
    PropertyInfo propertyField = type.GetProperty(propertyName);
    Type propertyType = propertyField.GetType();

    PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(TEntity).GetProperties();
    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
    {
        var displayAttribute = prop.GetCustomAttributes(false).FirstOrDefault(a => a.GetType() == propertyType);
        if (displayAttribute != null)
        {
            var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "x");
            var memberExpression = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameterExpression, prop.Name);
            var memberExpressionConversion = Expression.Convert(memberExpression, typeof(object));
            var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, object>>(memberExpressionConversion, parameterExpression);                    
        }
    }

    ISpecification<TEntity> Specification = new EntityByCustomSpecification<TEntity>(***Reflection_Expression***);

    context.CreateDbSet<TEntity>().Where(Specification.SatisfiedBy()),
}
```

I don't know whether this code can be part of the solution in order to create (***Reflection_Expression***) at least in regards to propertyName variable. 
I really can't manage to create (***Reflection_Expression***) as a lambda Expression and at the end get for that ***Reflection_Expression*** the implementation of...

```
(t1 => t1.name == "test_name")
```

... when TEntity is t1, propertyName is name, its value propertyValue is "test_name" and the operator propertyOperator is "=="

Any help, please???

Many thanks indeed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given

```
public class EntityByCustomSpecification<TEntity> : Specification<TEntity> where TEntity : class, new()
{
    Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> _Expression = null;

    public EntityByCustomSpecification(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> expression)
    {
        this._Expression = expression;
    }

    public override Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> SatisfiedBy()
    {
        return this._Expression;
    }
}
```

(it isn't clear if you already have it)

What you want is:

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetBySpecification<TEntity>(object propertyValue, string propertyName = "name", ExpressionType operation = ExpressionType.Equal) where TEntity : class, new()
{
    ParameterExpression par = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity));

    Expression left = Expression.PropertyOrField(par, propertyName);
    Expression right = Expression.Constant(propertyValue, left.Type);

    Expression comparison;

    try
    {
        comparison = Expression.MakeBinary(operation, left, right);
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException)
    {
        // string case, for example
        Type icomparable = typeof(IComparable<>).MakeGenericType(left.Type);

        if (!left.Type.GetInterfaces().Any(x => x == icomparable))
        {
            throw;
        }

        InterfaceMapping interfaceMap = left.Type.GetInterfaceMap(icomparable);
        int ix = Array.FindIndex(interfaceMap.InterfaceMethods, x => x.Name == "CompareTo");
        MethodInfo method = interfaceMap.TargetMethods[ix];

        // left.CompareTo(right) [operation] 0
        comparison = Expression.MakeBinary(operation, Expression.Call(left, method, right), Expression.Constant(0));
    }

    if (comparison.Type != typeof(bool))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("operationType");
    }

    Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(comparison, par);

    ISpecification<TEntity> specification = new EntityByCustomSpecification<TEntity>(lambda);

    var result = context.Set<TEntity>().Where(specification.SatisfiedBy());
    return result;
}
```

Note that to make it simpler, instead of a `string propertyOperator` it accepts an `ExpressionType`. `ExpressionType` has all the comparison operators (`<`, `<=`, `==`, `>=`, `>`), plus the math operators that you can ignore (`+`, `-`...). You can easily write a method that given a `string` returns the right `ExpressionType`.

I've corrected a bug with nullable types. I've added support for `string` through the `IComparable<T>` interface.

Comment: Now what should be some way of getting the comparison Expression to work with strings, since if I set operation = "Expression.GreaterThan" and the propertyValue is of type string.......  BinaryExpression comparison = Expression.MakeBinary(operation, left, right);  ..... does not work

Comment: @ForumAccount A big switch `ExpressionType operation; switch (stringop) case "==": operation = ExpressionType.Equal; break; case ">=": operation = ExpressionType.`

Comment: The thing is that operator types like "GreaterThan" for example do not work with String or DateTime...

Comment: @ForumAccount For `string`, even in LINQ it is invalid to do `x => x.MyString >= x.MyString`. For `DateTime` I should have fixed it. It wasn't a problem with `DateTime` but with nullable fields. For strings you have to do `x.MyString.CompareTo(x.MyString) >= 0` to do the `>=` comparison.

Comment: @ForumAccount Added support for `string`. It uses the `CompareTo`

Comment: Thanks! I managed with nullables by doing the Expression like this: left = Expression.PropertyOrField(par, propertyName);
                Expression right = Expression.Constant(propertyValue);

                BinaryExpression comparison = null;
                if (left.Type.Name.Contains("Nullable"))
                {
                    left = Expression.Convert(left, right.Type);
                }
                
                comparison = Expression.MakeBinary(operation, left, right);